# How to check for null in where clause for TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF value?

Tags: mysql

We could run mysql query with a where clause as this

```
TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('2012-08-22 06:25:12',lastEventTime)) >70
```

What we need to check now is for null values where have tried to put =null but is not showing up? What is needed ?

A sample query is as below and thank you it works. MY next question must I now index the lastEvenTime column?

```
SELECT 
    tblTimeLog.timeLogID,
    TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('2012-08-22 06:25:12',lastEventTime)) As timeDifference
FROM tblTimeLog
WHERE tblTimeLog.timeID = 2209
And (TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('2012-08-22 06:25:12',lastEventTime)) IS NULL  
  OR TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('2012-08-22 06:25:12',lastEventTime)) > 100)
```

Comment: Put your code in code blocks and at least tell us a bit more information

Comment: The MySQL comparison operator for checking NULL values is `column IS NULL` or `column IS NOT NULL`; (but not `column = NULL`)…

Comment: Can you provide full query that you trying.

Comment: @feela yes is null works perfectly so should I add an index for lastEventTime column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could replace this

```
And (TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('2012-08-22 06:25:12',lastEventTime)) IS NULL  
  OR TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('2012-08-22 06:25:12',lastEventTime)) > 100)
```

with

```
and (lastEventTime IS NULL  
OR TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('2012-08-22 06:25:12',lastEventTime)) > 100)
```

or use `coalesce` with a suitably chosen default (in case of `NULL`):

```
and TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('2012-08-22 06:25:12',
    coalesce(lastEventTime, '1900-01-01')) > 100
```

although the coalesce bit is only relevant for the `WHERE` clause; for the `SELECT` part you'd get `NULL` if lastEventTime is `NULL`.

Comment: So which is the best option you suggesting? I never used the coalesce? Should I index the lastEventTime which is a time based column?